# App for mapping in HTML canvas or SVG

Tags: web-apps, javascript, html, maps

I'm doing an app for a site to draw hex maps (like [this](https://i1.wp.com/i940.photobucket.com/albums/ad249/humble_inquisitor/DnD%20Hex%20Maps/Therund.jpg)).
The site is coded in python/django + javascript/jQuery. 
I have the hexes in .png format so all I have to do is combine them in a map.
What can I use? html canvas or SVG? and some library/app?

My app should have this functionalities:

1) load a map

2) let me pick a hex from somewhere outside the map (or I can have a special place inside the same canvas where I have all avaible hexes) and drag and drop on the map.

3) delete an hex from the map (and leave an empty hex)

4) move an hex around the map

5) save the map

6) pan the map

7) calcolate distances on the map (some hexes can count like two-three hexes so basically this means to sum an attribute of the hexes crossed by a line or better to have a function for calculate the minimum sum between two hexes and show the route)

8) have different layers on the map (for example: show/don't show city/hex number/political border)

So what can I use?

Maybe with canvas is easier to import images.png but is more difficult to move around the hexes. SVG is vector graphic and my map don't use vectors but for the other functionality I think is much better. Any idea?

Just now I'm tring [Raphael](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/)

Comment: Anyone can help me?